# Saving data to online text document

Tags: php

I have an issue which is i want to save the data to a online shared text document on google drive.
but it's not working. 
There is No error , it's just not saving anything into the document and i've already gived the document the full access by public.

```
////// email code
        require_once "Mail.php";    
        $from = "Babylovenappies <****@gmail.com>";
        $to = "nassim@*****.com";
        $recipients = $to;
        $subject = $subject;
        $body = $message;
        $host = "ssl://smtp.googlemail.com";
        $port = "465";
        $username = "****@gmail.com";
        $password = "****";
        $headers = array ('From' => $from,
        'To' => $to,
        'Bcc' => "admin@***.com.au",
        'Subject' => $subject,
        'MIME-Version' => "1.0",
        'Content-type' => "text/html; charset=iso-8859-1");
        $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
        array ('host' => $host,
        'port' => $port,
        'auth' => true,
        'username' => $username,
        'password' => $password));
        $mail = $smtp->send($recipients, $headers, $body);


        $fh = fopen('https://docs.google.com/document/d/1dS_MhqGnLkb22mwU6OKfxoiFcX0izRTvjjf8eJ7igiE/edit?usp=sharing', "a");
        fwrite($fh, $to);
        fclose($fh);
```

Thanks In Advance

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: `fwrite()` isn't going to magically write into the document and save it. You're going to have to use their API.

Comment: No you don't to use any API , 'cause if u go to your browser and even not signed in with gmail you can edit the doc file.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely should use API

Look at this: 
[Files: update](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/update)